# Callback when starting Android emulator with shell command via node

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, android-emulator

I am opening an android emulator with node via a shell script:

```
var process = require('child_process');

process.exec('~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86', processed);

function processed(data){
    console.log('processed called', data, data.toString());
}
```

I need to be able to detect when the emulator has finished loading so I can initiate a screen unlock and then launch the browser to a specified url (`~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell input keyevent 82` and `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com`)

However, when I launch the emulator I don't appear to get anything back and the process stays engaged with the emulator. When shutting the process down (ctrl+c) the emulator is closed along with it. (This is the same behaviour as running the shell command directly in the terminal)

1. Is it possible to know when the emulator has opened and loaded?
2. How can I execute additional commands when the process continues to
   run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like a boss.

I was able to set a timer to check once a second if the bootanimation had stopped. If it has, we know the emulator is open and booted.

```
var process         = require('child_process');

process.exec('~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86');

function isEmulatorBooted(){
    process.exec('~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell getprop init.svc.bootanim', function(error, stdout, stderr){

        if (stdout.toString().indexOf("stopped")>-1){

            clearInterval(bootChecker);
            emulatorIsBooted();
        } else {
            console.log('we are still loading');
        }
    });
}

function emulatorIsBooted(){
    //unlock the device
    process.exec('~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell input keyevent 82');

    //gotourl
    process.exec('~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://192.168.10.126:9876/');
}

bootChecker = setInterval(function(){
    isEmulatorBooted();
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for this, made an alternate version of Fraser's script - which also starts the actual emulator in a background process.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const process = require('child_process');

/* Get last emulator in list of emulators */
process.exec("emulator -list-avds|sed '$!d'", (_, stdout) => {
  console.log('[android emulator] Booting')

  /* Start emulator */
  process.exec(`nohup emulator -avd ${stdout.replace('\n', '')} >/dev/null 2>&1 &`)

  /* Wait for emulator to boot */
  const waitUntilBootedThen = completion => {
    process.exec('adb shell getprop init.svc.bootanim', (_, stdout) => {
      if (stdout.replace('\n', '') !== 'stopped') {
        setTimeout(() => waitUntilBootedThen(completion), 250)
      } else {
        completion()
      }
    })
  }

  /* When emulator is booted up */
  waitUntilBootedThen(() => {
    console.log('[android emulator] Done')
  })
})
```